# Proftpd "Can't open PID file /run/proftpd/proftpd.pid (Yet?)"

Tags: centos7, ftp, proftpd

I'm currently running into the following error with my Proftpd install:

```
Can't open PID file /run/proftpd/proftpd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

However when I run `ls /run/proftpd/` I'm presented with the following files, `proftpd.delay  proftpd.pid  proftpd.scoreboard  proftpd.scoreboard.lck  proftpd.sock` which proftpd.pid is definitely there.

I have tried a removing proftpd and reinstalling and it has resulted in the same error even with a fresh install.

I have also disabled SELinux as I saw online somewhere that could be causing the problem.

Any other ideas ?

Full status log:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status proftpd.service
● proftpd.service - ProFTPD FTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/proftpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-06-30 09:42:02 EDT; 6s ago
  Process: 30580 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/proftpd $PROFTPD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30581 (proftpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/proftpd.service
           └─30581 proftpd: (accepting connections)

Jun 30 09:42:02 xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting ProFTPD FTP Server...
Jun 30 09:42:02 xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /run/proftpd/proftpd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Jun 30 09:42:02 xxx.xxx.xxx proftpd[30581]: xxx.xxx.xxx - ProFTPD 1.3.5e (maint) (built Tue Sep 7 2021 10:34:22 UTC) standalone mode STARTUP
Jun 30 09:42:02 xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Started ProFTPD FTP Server.
```

Comment: The status output says it's running, what does it matter if it logs a message about not being able to open a file as part of startup if it's running properly afterwards?